# Cannot output png maps from folium with selenium and firefox

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, firefox, folium

I am trying to export a map I have made with folium in Python to a png format.
According to the post below, this can be made with selenium and the following command:

[Export a folium map as a png](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53565979/export-a-folium-map-as-a-png)

```
import io
from PIL import Image
import selenium 

img_data = map._to_png(5)
img = Image.open(io.BytesIO(img_data))
img.save('map_folium.png')
```

But I end up with the error:

```
TimeoutException: Message: Connection refused (os error 111)
```

In the help forums I have consulted to fix this error mention a problem with firefox not in path. But it is the case on my system. Has anyone encountered the same issue?

Answer (score 2):

Eventually, I have used another webdriver than Firefox to output the map:

```
import folium
from selenium import webdriver
import os
import time
import selenium

mapFname = 'folium_map.html'
mapUrl = 'file://{1}'.format(os.getcwd(), mapFname)

# use selenium to save the html as png image
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary = "path/to/waterfox")
driver.get(mapUrl)

# wait for 5 seconds for the maps and other assets to be loaded in the browser
time.sleep(5)
driver.save_screenshot('output.png')
driver.quit()
```