# Save geopandas explore() to jpeg

Tags: python, geospatial, folium

Based on the feature in the documentation

https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/user_guide/interactive_mapping.html

Does anyone know of a way to save these interactive plots as PNG or JPEG?

Tired save() but this didn't seem to work. Expected a replica of the interactive map produced in the notebook, but saved as a PNG to a directory.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of [Export a folium map as a png](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53565979/export-a-folium-map-as-a-png)

Comment: But probably it would be easier to convert a "static plot" to an image than an "interactive map". Or, if you are doing this interactively anyway, you could just create a screenshot.

Comment: When doing `mb21_plot = mb21_plot._to_png(5)
mb21_plot.save('my_map.png')`, I get the error `Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH. `. I considered screenshotting, but it just seems a little clunky and not very reproducible